# Каким способом можно автоматически заполнить авторство статьи? Django models.py

Tags: django

Каким методом, способом я могу сделать автоматическое заполнение автора статьи - `author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete = models.CASCADE)`? Возможно это как-то можно сделать с помощью `django.contrib.auth.get_user()` но, что передавать в качестве аргумента?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 55)
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date_create = models.DateField(auto_now = True)
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Страница добавления статьи в админке
[image: Страница добавления статьи в админке]

Comment: В коде, который создаёт статью, передавайте request.user в модель

Comment: Но в данный момент статьи формируются в отдельном HTML редакторе, и уже готовую статью добавляют через стандартную админку Django.

Comment: то есть автор не тот же самый человек что залогинен и добавляет ее?

Comment: Тогда можно переопределить метод save_model в ModelAdmin, в документации Django есть пример как раз про такую статью https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

Comment: Эмм проблема в том, что есть несколько авторов, так каждый может сделать статью не под своим авторством просто выбрав не real_author, а author22 (пример). Конечно можно подумать, что зачем реальном автору подписываться вторым автором, но мне кажется так оставлять все же не правильно..

Comment: Ну тогда переопределите save_model и запретите ручное изменение с помощью readonly_fields (тоже в документации есть)

Comment: https://django-crum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#get-current-user

Answer (score 2):

Можно попробовать вот так:

```py
# В файле models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        to=User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        editable=False, # Запретить изменения чтобы убрать из ручного редактирования
    )

   
# В файле admin.py
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    """
    Переопределяем метод сохранения модели
    """
        if not change: # Проверяем что запись только создаётся
            obj.author = request.user # Присваеваем полю автор текущего пользователя
    
        super(ArticleAdmin, self).save_model(
            request=request,
            obj=obj,
            form=form,
            change=change
        )
```

При добавлении из панели администратора будет брать данные профиля и записывать их